# Spring UserDetails and my User implementation in session

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm developing my Spring application with the support of Security Model.
I configured everything and it seems to work fine, but I have a conceptual question.
In my controller I can retrieve the User Details generated by Spring like this:

```
UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

Now, should I put this user in the Http session or it's useless?

And also, should I retrieve my User implementation on the basis of the UserDetails object and put it in the session?

What is the right way of thinking with security? I would need my user implementation to retrieve some information but I don't know to keep both around.

Comment: I believe by default Spring uses [HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolderStrategy.html), which uses HttpSession as the name implies.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/technical-overview.html#d4e731 in this docks 5.3.1 you can see example.

Something like this:

```
    Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```